# Ubuntu 19.04: How to create own whappapp, and make shortcuts to open it via keyboard?

Tags: shortcut, whatsapp

I want to make my own desktop app or shortcut and open whatsapp with one keyboard combination like  SUPER + W

> I found some whatsapp app but it's not offical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your own whatsapp app with these instructions:

- Type terminal `sudo -H gedit /usr/share/applications/whatsapp-webapp.desktop`
- Copy following text to opened screen

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Name=WhatsApp
GenericName=WhatsApp
Comment=WhatsApp desktop webapp
#Exec=webapp-container --store-session-cookies --webappUrlPatterns=https?://*.whatsapp.com/* --user-agent-string='Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36' https://web.whatsapp.com %u
Exec=/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome --app=https://web.whatsapp.com/
Terminal=false
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
MimeType=text/plain;
# If you want icon, type path of icon
# Icon=
Categories=Network;Application;
Keywords=WhatsApp;webapp;
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=WhatsApp
StartupWMClass=web.whatsapp.com
```

- Open shortcut window, click `+` the bottom of the window
- Set name `Whatsapp Chrome`
- Finally, keyboard shortcuts to open | create

```sh
bash -c "wmctrl -xa web.whatsapp.com || /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome --app=https://web.whatsapp.com/"
```

> `wmctrl` command used for focus or create app, to install it type `sudo apt install wmctrl`

Comment: What do you mean by shortcut window?

Comment: Ubuntu shortcut window, you can search on Ubuntu Quick Search